# C++ Inheritance: Do I have to repeat parent attributes in derived classes?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

If I separate my classes into header/implementation files, is it possible to have inheritance without needing to redeclare inherited attributes in the child class?

Let me clarify with an example. Why is this allowed (taken from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm)):

```c++
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class
class Shape {
   public:
      void setWidth(int w) {
         width = w;
      }
      void setHeight(int h) {
         height = h;
      }

   protected:
      int width;
      int height;
};

// Derived class
class Rectangle: public Shape {
   public:
      int getArea() { 
         return (width * height); 
      }
};

int main(void) {
   Rectangle Rect;

   Rect.setWidth(5);
   Rect.setHeight(7);

   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total area: " << Rect.getArea() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

But this isn't (try compiling [here](http://cpp.sh/74cvx)):

```c++
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// HEADER FILE
class Person {   
public:
    virtual void speak() = 0;

protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
};

class Programmer : public Person {
public:
    Programmer(std::string, std::string);
};

// CPP FILE
Programmer::Programmer(std::string name, std::string surname) : 
    name(name), 
    surname(surname) 
{}

void Programmer::speak(){
    std::cout << "My name is " + name + " " + surname + " and I like to code!";
}
```

Comment: You didn't declare `Programmer` to implement a function called `speak` - and there are situations where you wouldn't create an override for a `virtual` function in a class (this is generally true for any OOP language)

Comment: @UnholySheep But what about the attributes `name` and `surname`? I get errors about `Programmer` not having those too.

Comment: That is because they are protected. A completely different cause for the error.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what is confusing. Member initializer list only allows to specify base class(es) or direct members of this class. Because of that, your second example is not compiling.

At the same time, derived classes have access to `public` and `protected` member of their base(s), so this is why first example is OK.

An interesting observation is that following code will compile:

```
Programmer::Programmer(std::string name_, std::string surname_) {
    name = name_;
    surname = surname_;
}
```

Note, this will mean `name` and `surname` will be first default-initialized (to empty strings) and than they will be assigned to the values passed in the `Programmer` constructor. This is efficiency loss, which might be very noticeable under certain circumstances.

The proper way of solving this idiomatically is buy giving `Person` a constructor which accepts two string arguments and initializes the members, and than calling this constructor from `Programmer` constructor.

Comment: What's confusing me is how can `getArea()` refer to `width` and `height` (which are `protected` in `Shape`), but I cannot in the same way refer to `name` and `surname` in the `Programmer` constructor.

Comment: @LukeCollins you are not referring to them "in the same way" - if you put the assignments in the constructor body it works the same way as your first example. Member initializer lists are different.

Comment: @LukeCollins the answer is simple - because this is the way C++ is designed. Initializing the members is responsibility of the class constructor (this is the whole point!), but derived classes have access to those members.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant. So putting them in the body is the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Programmer` constructor, in the initializer list the variables initialized can only be variables directly from that class or a base class constructor.

But in the body of the member functions/constructors inherited variables can be used, if they are effectively `public` or `protected`.